# Office Communicator Crashes when opened

Tags: microsoft-office, office-communicator-2007

Since yesterday, the moment I open Office Communicator 2007 r2, it crashes. It appears momentarily in task manager and disappears. Reinstalling didn't help. How to get to root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to run the newest cumulative update for Office Communicator 2007 R2 from Microsoft posted January 2010:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976135

Comment: I am having the same issue but for me it appears to be as it tries to connect to Exchange on BPOS. Just constantly crashes. I have installed the hotfix you note, but it still does it.